# How to insert a list of lists into SQLite with executemany

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.x

I'm trying to insert a lot of rows into a sqlite table and so am seeking to use `executemany`.

I have a setup like this:

```
data_list = [['apples',10,'red'],['bananas',5,'yellow']]

dbc.executemany('
   insert into table
   (fruit, colour)
   values
   (?,?)',
   (data_list[0],data_list[2]))
```

As you can see, I don't want everything from the `data_list`, in this case, I don't want the number.

The problem is, I get this error despite the fact I specified which items from the list to use:

`sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 3 supplied.`

How do I get my data into sqlite using executemany? I really don't want to have to massage the data into the correct length (and order?) list - is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I must be honest, I don't know about databases. On the other hand, data_list has only two elements. You can't call data_list[2] cause that's data_list's third element (which does not exist). if you want `['apples',10,'red']` you should type `data_list[0]` , if you want `['bananas',5,'yellow']` you should type `data_list[1]` . From what I understand  you don't want the numbers, therefore i would create two new lists with the same content except for the numbers.

```
data_list = filter(lambda x : x not in range(1000) , data_list[0]),
filter(lambda y : y not in range(1000)  , data_list[1])
```

Now data_list is equal to data_list = [['apples','red'],['bananas',yellow']]

Comment: I'm afraid that's not how `executemany` works from my testing. It iterates over the list, so `data_list[0]` contains "apples" for the first insert and then "bananas" for the second. Counter-intuitive, but that seems to be how it works.

Comment: I am truly sorry then, but you motivated me to learn sql and operate the counterpart module in python! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since you are inserting only partial data, the most instinctive solution probably is using `execute()` instead of `executemany()`. If you don't have too much data, this won't slow down you too much.

But if you really want to use `executemany()`, you probably need `zip()` and zip the data twice. In the medium, `list()` is used to supply the subscript feature. Here is my code:

```
data_list = [['apples',10,'red'],['bananas',5,'yellow']]
firstZip = list(zip(*data_list))
secondZip = zip(firstZip[0], firstZip[2])
dbc.executemany('insert into fruitTable (fruit, colour) values (?,?)', 
                secondZip)
```

Noting that `executemany()` takes iterable of sequence as the input. So if only one variable is needed and a 1-D list is used as the input, `zip()` should also be used to eliminate the ValueError:

```
dbc.executemany('insert into fruitTable (fruit) values (?)', zip(fruitNameList))
```